# When does the second half of an NBA game start?

Tags: basketball, nba

I'm from Europe so it's hard for me to stay awake for the whole match, so I'm asking how much in total with commercials and time-outs, when does second half tip off?

Answer (score 2):

On average, NBA games will take a total of 2 hours and 15 minutes. You can expect the second half to start around 1 hour and 15 minutes after the tip off.

E.g. Game tips off at 7:30, 1st half will end around 8:30, 15 minute halftime, and 2nd half will start around 8:45.

Here is a Forbes article which has the average duration of games over the last few seasons: https://www.forbes.com/sites/shlomosprung/2018/12/11/nba-games-are-longer-this-year-and-the-league-is-ok-with-that-stressing-game-flow-as-more-important/#27276fbb2503